# Get all ID of input box that contains a class

Tags: jquery, html, class, alert, attr

How can i get the ID of an input box that contains a certain class value

*ex:*

```
<input id="first" class="failed" />
<input id="last" class="failed" />
<input id="city" class="failed" />
<input id="state" class="failed" />
```

I want to alert all the ID that contains the class failed after pushing a button or a command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to alert all the ID that contains the class failed after
>   pushing a button or a command.

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get elements with particular class. You can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to traverse all the element. Bind the click event to button, you can use button id in id selector to bind the event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xFp82/1/)**

Html

```
<input id="first" class="failed" />
<input id="last" class="failed" />
<input id="city" class="failed" />
<input id="state" class="failed" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
```

*Javascript*

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('.failed').each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: we have a winner! you can claim your price after 5 mins

Answer (score 5):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of ids

```
var ids = $('.failed').map(function(){
    return this.id
}).get();

console.log(ids);
alert(ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

use each jquery

```
$('.failed').each(function(e){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');//find each id 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('.failed'), function () {alert ($(this).attr('id')); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = []; //create an array
$('.failed').each(function(e)){   //iterate each class
    ids.push($(this).prop('id')); //push their id to array
});
alert(ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the inputs and do what ever you want with elements that have the defined class:

```
$("input.failed").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alert all `ids` on `button click` like this:

```
$("#btnid").click(function(){    //click on button
    $('.failed').each( function () {
       alert ($(this).attr('id')); //alert id one by one
  });
});
```